# How to set price of product by user, prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Im trying to set custom price for some products entered by user. Simply i have a module with form, and i want user to input price. then the data from user will be used to check out.

Basically, user inputs 45$ for product, he click submit, and i want the product appear in the cart with the price that user specified.

i tried some of these prestashop methods, but there is no way to set price, just quantity and pruduct_id

```
$cart->updateQty(1,2 );
```

Comment: You need to add user specific price before adding to cart.

Comment: can you be more specific please ? is there any function to set specific price to one user implemented in prestashop?

Comment: not price exactly, but you can specify discount for a particular customer group and add the customer to that specific group.
e.g.10%OFF group etc. Or you can apply create coupon runtime and set the coupon code discount as per price entered by user.

Comment: i know i can do that, but what i want is to set specific price by PHP to customer